# Facebook rejected - iOS Simulator build configured incorrectly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Frustrating !!**

I created a simulator build for `publish_actions` submission review to the Facebook by [following these Steps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review/#generate-simulator).

I got the Successful Build as I got the output from the build tools followed by the string `** BUILD SUCCEEDED **` in my terminal.

Before uploading, I tested my simulator build by running `ios-sim launch <path to .app>` and verified that the app opens in the simulator successfully.

I then compressed the simulator build into a **zip file** and submitted for the review process.

It got rejected by Facebook with this response :

> **iPhone**
>
> Your provided file has been configured incorrectly. For iOS
> Simulator Builds, follow our instructions and resubmit. For Android
> submissions, please build a .APK file for upload.

I am not getting what is not configured correctly.

**Can anyone please help me with this? Any steps that I am missing?**

Comment: So what the issue was ? Having same problem...

Comment: I am having the same issue. Up till now I tried submitting the app twice, and it was rejected twice. The 1st time it was an `.ipa` file (which is really just a renamed `.zip` with the `.app` folder in the root `ZIP\Payload\blabla.app`), and the 2nd time it was a `.zip` containing the _contents_ of the `.app` folder, packaged according to the FB guidelines. I suspect they want to have an `.app` folder inside the `.zip`.... This will go in my 3rd attempt...

Comment: Any solution yet, Bhavin? I have the same problem and it's infuriating

Answer (score 0):

(Putting my comment into an answer after it turned out to work)

I would like to point out that **only the following** is the expected structure:

```
-- YOURAPPNAME.zip
    |-- YOURAPPNAME.app
        |-- <app contents>
```

These versions **do NOT pass review**:

1. Direct zipping of the `<app contents>`:

   ```
   -- YOURAPPNAME.zip
       |-- <app contents>
   ```
2. [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa_%28file_extension%29) packaging:

   ```
   -- YOURAPPNAME.zip
       |-- Payload
           |-- YOURAPPNAME.app
               |-- <app contents>
   ```

I hope this helps!